# SVN -> GIT without HTTP access

Tags: git, macos, svn, bitbucket

I'm trying to figure out how I can take a svndump file and migrate it to GIT with bitbucket cloud. All the tutorials assume that the svn repo is currently setup with apache. But that is actually the reason for my migration as I have been unsuccessful in getting mod_dav_svn re-installed after rebuilding a mac server (10.13).

I was able to create a dump file of the svn repo I want to migrate. It would be nice to keep the commit history and not have to do a clean import.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this so I cannot say you will have success.  But there are some tools that look to be specific to your issue.

Check this out:  https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/svn-migration-scripts/src

Personally, I went the mod_dav_svn route and it was a bit of a challenge to get set up, but once I did I found that svn2git really did the bulk of the work.

If you are interested, you can check this out too:  https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git

Here is my apache config:

```
# apache_svn_dav.conf
# Not safe to use in production.
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath /opt/svnroot

    Deny from All
    Allow from localhost
</Location>
```

I was then able to checkout each svn repo I needed to migrate, like so:

```
# svn co http://localhost/repos/reponame
```

I was able to retain all of my history for most of my svn repos using the svn2git method, some of my svn repos did not have the standard directory structure (e.g.,):

```
/trunk
/branches
/tags
```

Should you decide to go this route here are the commands that I used:

## Create an authors file for git (note: email address)

```
# svn log -q http://servername/repos/reponame | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2"@email.address>"}' | sort -u > authors.txt
```

## Conversion process

```
# svn2git http://servername/repos/reponame --authors authors.txt
```

Then you should be provided a .git repository you can then upload.

I decided to go with my own selfhosted GitLab, but the commands should be similar:

```
# git remote add origin git@servername:gitlab-group/project.git
# git add .
# git push --all origin
```